# Controlling servo via serial port without any delay

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I have such code:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {

}
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
   Serial.println(Serial.readString()); 
  }
  }
```

When I send there something - it's sent with a delay (1-2 seconds). How can I make it so that Serial.readString() is carried out without delay?

Please, help me)

Comment: Don't use `readString` - it has a 1 second timeout. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: @Majenko, hmm... In serial port i got such string: engine:100b. How i can got key (engine) and value (100)?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c

Answer (score 0):

`readString()` uses a 1 second timeout to determine when the end of a string occurs. It's not suitable for anything - I have no clue why they included it in the API.

Instead you need to read the data a character at a time (as and when characters become available) and use a suitable string termination indicator to trigger processing of the string.

A common termination indicator is `\n` (line feed) or `\r\n` (carriage-return followed by line feed).

Read each character when it arrives on the serial port and add it to a string (not a String, a string - a NULL-terminated array of `char`). Only when you see `\n` arrive should you then start examining the string to see what you have received, and act on it accordingly.

I have a blog post [here](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino) that details reading from serial, and another one [here](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c) that shows you some techniques for splitting up strings (`strtok()` is a useful function). There's also plenty of other questions here about splitting strings with answers detailing similar methods.